# Rails 3 Migration and application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I inherited a Rails project and was asked to update it so I am migrating the Rails 2.2.2 project to Rails 3.2.

I went through a few migration tutorials and ran the rails upgrade script and it loads fine when the default /public/index.html is there.

I then went ahead and removed /public/index.html, so the app would point to the file indicated in routes.rb and then I get:

```
LoadError (Expected /var/www/vendor_sandbox/app/controllers/application.rb to define Application):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The file that is causing the error was from the original Rails 2.2.2 code base. I left it because there was no indication in the migration docs that I was reading that mentioned removing it but clearly something is wrong.

I find it strange that I now have a Rails 3 version of application.rb in /config and an application.rb in /app/controllers/

Not sure what to do with /app/controllers/application.rb.

Here are the files mentioned:

```
 #### /app/controllers/application.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

# See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
# Uncomment the :secret if you're not using the cookie session store
protect_from_forgery # :secret => 'mysecretkey'

# See ActionController::Base for details 
# Uncomment this to filter the contents of submitted sensitive data parameters
# from your application log (in this case, all fields with names like "password"). 
# filter_parameter_logging :password

def authenticate
  return true if session[:user_id].to_i > 0
  session[:after_login] = params
  redirect_to :controller => "login"
  return false
end

def authenticate_admin
  user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @nav = [{:title => "Home", :action => {:controller => "home"}}]
  return true if user and user.is_admin?
  redirect_to :controller => "login"
  return false
end

def clean_date_for_4D date
  return "00/00/00" if !date or date == ""
  return date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if date.class.to_s == "Date"
  return Date.parse(date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # assume it's a string
end

def pad text, length=20
  while text.length < length do
    text = text + " "
   end
  return text
 end
end


 #### /config/routes.rb
 VendorSandbox::Application.routes.draw do

 match '/' => 'home#index'
 match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
end


#### /config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)

  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))

end

module VendorSandbox
  class Application < Rails::Application


    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the   log file.
  config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Session key
     config.session_store(:cookie_store, {:key => '_vendor_sandbox_session', :secret => 'secretkey'

    # Time zone
   config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)' #'UTC' # Had to change this to keep created_at from being 4 hours in advance!
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying renaming your `app/controllers/application.rb` to `application_controller.rb`.

I think Rails is expecting your controller to be named with a `_controller` suffix, and the `application.rb` you have in your controllers folder isn't following that convention.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on @Zajn answer, but I don't have the required "50 reputation".

Just for reference, `app/controllers/application.rb` was renamed to `application_controller.rb` in Rails 2.3

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#application-controller-renamed